# Installing OpenStreetMap Tile Server with Custom Projection Systems?

Tags: openstreetmap, coordinate-system, tiles, mapnik

I am trying to install the OSM tile server on a local machine with a custom projection system like epsg:3573. For the server installation I followed this tutorial (http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/) and it works fine with the default settings. For making changes, I played around with osm.xml and changed the srs information in there but still no luck.

Can anyone give me some hints on customizing the OSM tile server with a custom projection system?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was thinking of manipulating OSM.XML file to change the projection information and get a reprojected map on-the-fly. For example, I followed [this tutorial](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik_GB_Projection) but could not get the result.

Just wondering if you have any experience in this regard?

---

To have a map with a custom projection (rather than OSM default EPSG:3857), you just need to change the SRS information in the Map element within the OSM.XML and Mapnik will do the rest. Do not forget to flush the cache after making changes.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend to alter the projection already at the DB level, as a lot of tools rely on the default projection for OSM: Instead try to use e.g. [Mapproxy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapProxy) to reproject the output tiles.